# Compilation Error using Custom Sort inside Class

Tags: c++, class, c++11

I am trying to use custom sort inside a class,
such as `sort(arr,arr+n,cust);`
inside a class function.
Custom sort looks like this:

```
bool cust (int a, int b) {
  return pos[a]<pos[b];
}
```

Where `pos` is an array inside class.
But it does not compile, and gives compilation error

> "invalid use of non-static member function"
>   how to get rid of compilation error.

my code -> https://pastebin.com/W1zw0A5s

I have tried writing:

```
static bool cust (int a, int b) {
     /* same code */
}
```

which hasn't helped.

Comment: Please post the minimal code here as the pastebins might get removed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the pastebin link, this function is a member function in your class. You need to bind the `this` pointer to it in order to use it:

```
sort(sa,sa+n, [this](int a, int b){ return this->sufCmp(a,b); } );
```

Comment: I tried it but now it gives invalid use of member SuffixArray::pos in static member function and same for gap and n

Comment: Edited my answer to avoid static member function.

Comment: But now it has started giving "invalid use of member variable" such as gap, pos, n that i have used in comparator function.  PLEASE HELP

Comment: get rid of the static...

Comment: Can you please tell me some sources to read about C++ so that I can handle these problems on my own.

Comment: @vikram We have a nice [list of good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn from :)